# Python app hosted on app engine is not able to connect with Firestore where as working on local

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a new project on GCP. I am trying to select/add data from firestore (already in native mode) from Python flask app. From local env. I am able to connect to firestore. But once I hosted my app on App engine, my API is not able to connect with Firestore. It's throwing the below error:

TypeError: with_scopes_if_required() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default_scopes'

_create_composite_credentials (/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py:238)

I am not sure what I am missing here. I appreciate any support.

Thanks

Comment: I'd the same problem after just deploy a new version on app engine.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, and I just fixed it today.

As you can see in the changelog https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/changelog.html recently they have updated the requirements for `google-auth` lib.
You need to check your requirements.txt.
In my case, we had two libs pinned that we weren't using directly.

```
google-auth==1.21.1
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
```

I just removed them from the `requirements.txt` so that dependencies versions are handled automatically, and it solved the issue.

So I guess it depends on your case, on how you are managing dependencies, but you might want to play with `google-auth` versions.

Comment: In my case I removed all specific versions from requirements.txt, deployed again and problem solved.

Comment: It also works on the latest version `google-auth==1.30.1`